# Twillio StatusCallBack Webhook

Tags: jsp, servlets, twilio

Does anyone has any example of using status callback for  in Java (JSP/Servlet)?

If I make a couple of calls using Dial, I am having difficulty in updating the view (JSP) to show the current progress of each call.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

I created a servlet which is called by the Twilio Webhook. I created a static class which sets a few properties when the servlet is called by the webhook. Than I used [Server Sent Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to update the view based on the property of static class.